# How do I clone std::string contents to a new char[] array

Tags: c++, stdstring

Given a `std::string`, how do I concisely (i.e. a single line/function call) allocate a char array freeable with `delete[]` of a suitable size and clone the string's contents into the char array as a null terminated string?

I could do this:

```
m_name = new char[name.size() + 1];
(void)name.copy(m_name, name.size());
m_name[name.size()] = '\0';
```

But it is not concise. What I really need is a function like:

```
size_type std::basic_string::clone(CharT** dest);
CharT* std::basic_string::clone();
```

That doesn't exist as far as I can see.

A company I used to work for implemented their own standard library which included a `strnewdup()` function, which worked just like `strdup()` but using `new`, to avoid code duplication. Something like that would work fine, but I cannot find any reference to something like that in the standard C++ library.

I would prefer a solution that only uses the standard C++ library and not something like Boost or writing my own code.

Comment: Can you tell us why (1) did not work for you? You said that the API expects `const char*` and that is exactly what `std::string::c_str()` returns, so there must be another error.

Comment: How do you create the object of the class? Your constructor should not take `std::string`, it should take `const std::string&`, otherwise the `std::string` will be destroyed after the constructor and the `std::string::c_str()` is invalid.

Comment: So I have figured out why 1) and 2) didn't work. You are right that I forgot to make the constructor parameter by reference (doh), but anyway I am adding the object to a std::list and it seems to destroy the added object and create a flat copy, so invalidating all my string members internal data pointers.

I still want to know how to clone the string contents in one line though.

Comment: Adding an object to a `std::list` (e.g. `some_list.push_back(some_string)` ) actually adds a copy.    If you want to use data from such a string, you need to use `c_str()` for the string that is stored in the list, not the original.

Comment: Please post your code instead of describing it in English. If what you describe in your post is true,  `std::string& and pass object->GetName().c_str()` will work fine. Now you are also describing that there is a std::list that could be very relevant to your issue, but we know nothing about these very important details, We only see what you have written here in your post,Now - since it does not work , you should. a) describe what "does not work" mean (what happens). b) show your code, it is much more precises and shorter to show the code than trying to describe your code.

Comment: @nos, I have removed much of the description of why I wanted to clone the string contents as it was distracting from the main question. I am not interested in solving the problem of why the memory pointers become invalidated, I just want to know if there is a concise way to create a "new" allocated char array/string as a clone of the contents of a std::string.

Comment: Am I too pragmatic? Wrap it into a function. Move on. If you ever find a library function, just do a search-replace.

Comment: "But it is not concise." - why not?

Comment: @AlastairG In that case, your option is resort to the `<cstring>` header and do `char *s = strdup(m_name.c_str());`  and remember to `free(s);` when done with it, or make your own strdup like function (that perhaps use new/delete instead) that you can re-use wherever you need. (It is however much easier to fix the underlying problem or at least find a way to use a std::string though, so you don't need to deal with the manual memory management)

Comment: @David: It's three lines of code. Imagine I have a hundred places in my code where I want to do this. That's 300 lines of code that might contain typo's leading to all sorts of problems, rather than just one. I want a single easy to use API, rather than having to write my own. Something like `m_name = name.clone();`. That's concise!

Comment: why won't you wrap these 3 lines in a function?

Comment: @nos: I am trying to write C++ code so don't want to mix delete and free(). I am also trying to avoid writing my own version of strnewdup() which will then need porting everywhere I want to do something like this.

I am flabberghasted that there does not appear to be any way to do such an obvious and simple thing using the standard C++ library. Anywhere that C++ code interfaces to a library that takes C strings without cloning them, this is needed.

Comment: @AlastairG What you want does not exist, I listed your 2 options(or 3 options if you include fixing the underlying problem and just use a std::string) in the previous comment

Comment: @David: I want to find a standard library function because if I code my own version I end up having to port that function to every project i ever work on that I need that functionality.

Years ago I had my own little collection of miscellaneous functions with an implementation of strnewdup(). I ended up copying it here and there and everywhere and ending up with loads of versions and it was a nuisance. Such a function is too small to be worthy of its own library and anyway such a library then requires so much maintenance even if I commonalise it.

Comment: @nos: Smeg. So it looks like I have asked an unanswerable question. I am amazed that such an obvious and simple piece of functionality is not already part of std::string to be honest. I mean they have the `copy()` function, and it's frankly a bit crap. I mean making a copy of the string and not even null terminating it? Or having an optional parameter to null terminate it? Not having an option to allocate the memory either?

Comment: No matter how much stuff is going to be added to the standard, there are going to be items which seem to be essential yet missing. It happens with everybody with every project. Perhaps it's time to learn to deal with these problems? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C++ library does not implement the required functionality.

Bummer.